# How to test to test if one model is better than another on independent dataset?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, predictive-models, permutation-test, model-evaluation, sign-test

I have two models that make predictions on the same independent data set. I would like to make a test and find out if one model is statistically significantly better than another.

I've read that Mcnerman test can be used to test if the proportion of correctly classified samples is better. What test to use if I want to test if the model makes a better prediction in terms of AUC or some other measure? On this website, I saw people recommending bootstrap, but I have only one independent test set, so I think there should be a simpler solution.

I think that a permutation absed sing test is the appropriate think to do, but I am not sure and I cannot get my head around it.

Comment: I suggest to read and play with the provided code in "Time for a Change: A Tutorial for Comparing Multiple Classifiers Through through Bayesian Analysis" http://jmlr.org/papers/v18/16-305.html

Comment: One day, I will dive deep into bayesian waters, but at this moment I really need a p-value.

Comment: But avoid classification and the improper accuracy scoring rule of proportion "classified" "correctly".  I cover this topic in my Regression Modeling Strategies course, book, and notes: http://fharrell.com/links

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what i am trying to do. I want to compare if one model is better in terms of auc or log score or brier score. But i don't know how to do it corretly. Btw: great book, it helped me a lot

Comment: @rep_ho The paper shows how to compare using p-values as well.